# Published site updates not being shown in multiple browsers

Tags: caching, browser, upload, refresh

Apologies if this is a really simple one. I'm learning HTML, CSS, Javascript in my retirement for fun. I have a site published on Hostinger and I've managed to link it to my GitHub using a webhook so that commits to the main branch trigger a deployment onto the production site. All is working well in that I can confirm using Hostinger File Manager that the deployments are happening and that the script.js file reflects changes committed.

However loading the updated site on either my PC or mobile (Android) web browsers is showing me a previous version.

I must be missing something really dumb here. Any pointers gratefully received.

After committing my latest change I can see (using the Hostinger File Manager) that script.js has been updated properly and my changes are present. However loading the site on either my Windows PC (Edge) or Android mobile (Chrome) web browsers is showing me a previous version. I expected to see the uploaded changes.

Inspecting the loaded page, the script.js source is indeed an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing browser cache resulted in the updated site loading correctly. Knew it would be something dumb.

That's a pain though. Right now it's only for my use, but once I publish the game I'm building I don't want to have to instruct visitors to clear cache whenever I commit a change? Is there a way to stop the page from caching and force a proper load ?

Comment: You should create another question the question in your answer.